# Difference between lambda syntax and addressof VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, lambda

I've recently entered the joyful world of VB.NET, for the life of me however, I can't seem to figure out why the following is not working.

When I write this code here, all is well:

```
MyNavigationCommand = New RelayCommand(AddressOf Navigate)

Private Sub Navigate()
    Navigator.NavigateTo(NavigationRoutes.DetailScreen)
End Sub
```

However, when I try to do exactly the same using the lambda syntax, my code inside the lambda doesn't get hit when I click the button  that triggers the command.

The following line, doesn't work:

```
MyNavigationCommand = New RelayCommand(Sub() Navigator.NavigateTo(NavigationRoutes.DetailScreen))
```

This should work exactly the same as my previous approach, shouldn't it? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Is Navigator.NavigateTo a shared sub or relying on some property? And what does NavigateTo actually do?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what's going wrong for you. This is my code that I wrote to test this:

```
Sub Main

    Dim MyNavigationCommand = New RelayCommand(AddressOf Navigate)
    Dim MyNavigationCommand2 = New RelayCommand(Sub() Console.WriteLine("!"))

    Navigate
    MyNavigationCommand
    MyNavigationCommand2

End Sub

Public Delegate Sub RelayCommand

Public Sub Navigate()
    Console.WriteLine("!")
End Sub
```

When run this code produces three lines of `!`.

Comment: Like you say, it works when doing something as simple as that. However, when you pass a closure to the RelayCommand's Action, it no longer works. I've resolved the issue, it was tied to how MVVM Light's RelayCommand handles captured variables in the lambda passed to the command. 

Implementing ICommand myself and passing a captured variable does the trick. Strangely enough.

Comment: @Mirage - Can you explain where you are passing a closure? I don't see a difference between `Sub() Console.WriteLine("!")` & `Sub() Navigator.NavigateTo(NavigationRoutes.DetailScreen)`. Unless `NavigationRoutes.DetailScreen` is not just a regular type?